# Is there a plugin for Wordpress that lets me show HTML/JS/CSS examples?

Tags: javascript, css, html, wordpress

Are there any Wordpress plugins that let me show inline in a page or a post some HTML, Javascript and CSS, and let the user see it running as well as see the code? Essentially I'm looking for something a little bit like a JSFiddle that I can render inline as a way to demonstrate how certain functionality works.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just embed a jsfiddle. It allows you to see all the code, and run the result.

Take a look here for docs: http://doc.jsfiddle.net/use/embedding.html

And an example embed: http://bit.ly/1aFKGO7